# Generating random longs with uniform distribution inside a range java.

Tags: java, random, cryptography, distribution, uniform-distribution

I need to generate an unspecified number of longs that are cryptographically secure have a uniform distribution and are within a given range. 
Will this produce what I need:

```
    SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
    LongStream l = rand.longs(streamsize, randomNumberOrigin, 
                              randomNumberBound);
    long[] rands = l.toArray();
    return rands;
```

Are there any other better methods?

Comment: "Will this produce what I need" What does the Javadoc say about the methods you're using?

Comment: @user8565662 What makes you think it wouldn't be uniform?

Comment: @Andreas the javadoc for other methods such as nextInt() specify the resulting distribution, but this method does not so I'm not sure.

Comment: @AndyTurner the javadoc does not specify the resulting distribution.

Comment: @user8565662 The javadoc doesn't explicitly specify the distribution, but it does specify the code for producing the `long` values, and that code ensures a uniform distribution. If the distribution wasn't uniform, it wouldn't be truly random, now would it?

Comment: @Andreas fair point. Can you help me understand how do you know from the code that it ensure a uniform distribution?

Comment: Side note, you can merge your four statements into one: `return new SecureRandom().longs(streamsize, randomNumberOrigin, randomNumberBound).toArray();`

Comment: @user8565662 It does the same thing the [`nextInt(int bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) method is doing to ensure uniform distribution of a bounded value.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for the help I appreciate it.

Comment: @Andreas do you know of a way to do the same thing but generating a single bounded long?

Comment: Write the code in the javadoc? It's kind of weird that they didn't add a `nextLong(long bound)` method when they added the `longs(...)` methods.

Comment: @Andreas "If the distribution wasn't uniform, it wouldn't be truly random, now would it?"  So you think that random variables with Gaussian, exponential, Weibull, beta, gamma, etc., distributions are not truly random?  Why do you think they're referred to as *random* variables?

Comment: @Andreas With the greatest respect, it's completely wrong to say that only a uniform distribution is "truly random". That's why we have java.util.random.nextGuassian(). There's a gazillion different ways for random data points to be distributed.